# Managing multiple where conditions with Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am fetching results from my `collection` using **3 search fields**.

If `this.tag` is empty I don't want this `.where("tagarray", "array-contains", this.tag)` to work, similarly if `this.dt` is empty `.where('lastActivityDate', '>=', this.dt)` should not work. Same for `this.leadstage`.

How do I manage this condition ?

```
  loadItems(){
    this.firestore.collection('leads' , ref => ref 
.where("tagarray", "array-contains", this.tag) 
.where('lastActivityDate', '>=', this.dt) 
.where("leadstage" , "==" , this.leadstage)
```

### Edit 1

My entire code of this function

```
loadItems(){
this.firestore.collection('leads' , ref => ref 
.where("tagarray", "array-contains", "tag1") //tag success
.where('lastActivityDate', '>=', '07-APR-2020') //date success
.where("leadstage" , "==" , 'Prospect') // leadstage success, this is case sensitive
.limit(5)
).snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
if(!response.length){
  console.log("no data available");
  return false;
}
this.tableData = [];
for(let item of response){
  var data = Object.assign(item.payload.doc.data(), {id : item.payload.doc.id})
  this.tableData.push(data);

...
```

### Edit 2

Screenshot of error

[image]

### Edit 3

Current code

```
    this.firestore.collection('leads' , (ref) => {
      let query = ref;
      if (this.tag) {
        query = query.where("tagarray", "array-contains", this.tag) 
      }
      if (this.dt) {
        query = query.where('lastActivityDate', '>=', this.dt) 
      }
      if (this.leadstage) {
        query = query.where("leadstage" , "==" , this.leadstage) 
      }
      return query; 
    }
    )
    .limit(5)
.snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
if(!response.length){
  console.log("no data available");
  return false;
}
...
```

Errors:

> Type 'Query' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'CollectionReference': id, parent, path, doc,
>   addts(2739)
>
> Property 'limit' does not exist on type
>   'AngularFirestoreCollection'.ts(2339)

Comment: my code is different than that one, someone is helping me, please dont close the question

Comment: You may edit your question, to add an **Edit 3** at the end, to explain why it is not a duplicate. Be detailed, and then ping @DougStevenson to say you have updated the question.

Comment: The answer given in that thread is using `get()` method , i have already achieved it with that but i am using `('leads' , ref => ref ....snapshotChanges()` and as per docs things are not working, @frank is also trying to help me, but till now it is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your query with multiple condition checks, like this:

```
this.firestore.collection('leads' , (ref) => {
  let query = ref;
  if (this.tag) {
    query = query.where("tagarray", "array-contains", this.tag) 
  }
  if (this.dt) {
    query = query.where('lastActivityDate', '>=', this.dt) 
  }
  if (this.leadstage) {
    query = query.where("leadstage" , "==" , this.leadstage) 
  }
  return query; 
})...
```

Comment: `loadItems(){
    let query = ref;
    if (this.tag) {....` cannot find name ref

Comment: i have edited question, copied entire function if you can have a look and guide accordingly

Comment: The `ref` in my answer is the same as what you use in your question in `ref => ref 
.where...`.

Comment: in my code its `('leads' , ref => ref)` , and when i type what you guided, it says cannot find name `ref`, i have copied my entire function, if you can have a look and update your answer, will be very helpful

Comment: I have updated my question, added screenshot , see `Edit:: 2`

Comment: Ah, I think I might have misunderstood the AngularFire API before. See the latest update to my answer, which puts the query building into the callback.

Comment: Still not resolved, i have updated the code in `Edit::3` error coming for `query` and `limit`